# Why boxes are invisible in checkbox?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, kotlin, styles

after created this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/offer_text_background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/settingsNotificationCategory</item>
</style>

<style name="settingsNotificationCategory">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

My box from checkbox is removing:

[invisible boxes](https://ibb.co/L1hWF85)

Without this style:

[visible boxes](https://ibb.co/vBkhbqW)

I need create chceckbox dynamically in kotlin:

```
var checkBox = CheckBox(this)
checkBox.text = category
checkBox.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.customText))
        checkBox.isChecked = true
notificationCategoryLayout.addView(checkBox)
```

what's happened?

I tried :

```
var checkBox = CheckBox(this, null, R.style.settingsNotificationCategory)
checkBox.text = category
checkBox.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.customText))
        checkBox.isChecked = true
notificationCategoryLayout.addView(checkBox)
```

but the effect is the same...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You are given the checkbox a style that contains only the textSize so it will affect on the style of the checkbox you can do 2 things:

first just set the textsize programatically:

```
checkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
```

or adjust your style to be like this:

```
<style name="settingsNotificationCategory" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

to inherit the base style of the checkbox

Comment: why you removed the green marker is something wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

but when I create checbox in layout:

```
 <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="test"
                            android:textColor="@color/customText"
                            android:theme="@style/settingsNotificationCategory"/>
```

this is working without

```
parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
```

is possible to set theme in code?
I want set textSize via style because I use layouts to different resolution (for large, xlarge, small sizes)

Comment: did you add the `parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompundButton.CheckBox` in your style and set your style pragmatically `var checkBox = CheckBox(this, null, R.style.settingsNotificationCategory)` ?

Comment: no, only var checkBox = CheckBox(this) and my style in AppTheme

Comment: I checked it again, You right, it is working now. Thank you !

Comment: Okay if the textSize is the only matter their is a better way, you can create different dimen.xml for different size and put your dimension for different layout size, example: `CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.checkboxtextsize));`

Comment: sorry I am using java - in kotlin 
`var checkbox = CheckBox(this)
        checkbox.textSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.checkboxSize)`

Comment: Thanks you again, I created checkbox in code badly. Correct is  `<style name="settingsNotificationCategory" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>` and   `var checkBox = CheckBox(this)`